# Plot multiple line plot with table from a data frame

Tags: r, plot, graph, line

I am trying to plot a multiple line graph to represent a frequency table such that under the graph along the x-axis, it also gives me the actual values for each of the series in a table. 
For e.g.:

if there are 3 values to plot on x-axis - 1,2,3;
frequencies for series A are 1 - 2 times, 2 - 5 times, 3 - 7 times;
frequencies for series B are 1 - 7 times, 2 - 5 times, 3 - 3 times.

Then under the x-axis of the line graph, table is formed such that frequencies of both series are listed under each x-value.

While I can create multi-line graph using *ggplot* I am not sure how to add the table.

Comment: A reproducible example would be great, as well as what you have tried so far (e.g. the ggplot code). So you are trying to "plot" a frequency table underneath the x axis as part of the graph? Any reason why you wouldn't have a (picture) graph, and the (text) table underneath?

Comment: That's because I was writing a statistical abstract which has many sets of graph and tables. And that was a great way to fit everything neatly without creating a long scroll in the document. Also excel has an option of creating a line graph in which you can add the freq. table in the same graph. So I wondered if that kind of an effect was possible in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
                 x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                 y = c(2, 5, 7, 7, 5, 3))
library(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
tbl <- tableGrob(t(df), rows = NULL,
                 theme = ttheme_minimal())
# Plot and table together
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plt, tbl,
             nrow = 2,
             as.table = TRUE,
             heights = c(3,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! @user3816784 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.